Assistance Needed with Webpack Module Resolution Errors in React Project
I'm reaching out to seek your expertise in troubleshooting some webpack module resolution errors that have recently surfaced in my React project. Despite several attempts at resolution, I'm still facing challenges in resolving these issues.
Error Details:
The errors primarily involve missing core Node.js modules such as 'zlib', 'querystring', 'path', 'crypto', 'fs', 'stream', 'http', and 'url'. Each error message provides insights into the specific module that couldn't be resolved, along with recommended solutions such as configuring fallbacks and installing necessary polyfills.
Steps Taken So Far:
Uninstallation and Cache Clearing: Initially, I attempted to resolve the issue by uninstalling the node_modules, clearing cache, and running npm audit fix --force. However, these standard troubleshooting steps didn't yield the desired results.
Review of Previous Code: Interestingly, the errors appeared suddenly without any package installation or updates. Upon reverting to a previous version of the codebase, the project worked without any issues, suggesting that the problem lies in the current configuration rather than the code itself.
Webpack Configuration: Following the error messages, I attempted to update the webpack configuration to include fallbacks for the missing modules. However, despite adding the necessary fallbacks, the errors persisted.
Polyfill Installation: I also tried installing the recommended polyfills using npm, including packages such as browserify-zlib, querystring-es3, crypto-browserify, stream-browserify, path-browserify, and url. Nevertheless, the errors remained unresolved.

Error in console
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\anura\Desktop\INDOOR-UNIT-PROJECT\indoor\node_modules\send'


BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 18:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\anura\Desktop\INDOOR-UNIT-PROJECT\indoor\node_modules\serve-static'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
webpack compiled with 25 errors and 6 warnings
